# RoR Hartl Tutorial Chapter 9.3 Failing Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec

I'm try hard to best this Hartl 9.3 test to pass but am having no luck.

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit page"
```

Terminal returns

```
sis-macbook-pro:sample_app Lagaspi$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit page"
/Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load': /Users/Lagaspi/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:111: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

I think the problem may be in this file, `spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do
  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button "Create my account" }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "error messages" do
        before { click_button "Create my account" }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
       end
     end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect do
          click_button "Create my account"
        end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button "Create my account" }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end
    end
  end
end

describe "signup page" do
  before { visit signup_path }

  it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

describe "signup" do
  before { visit signup_path }

  let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

  describe "with invalid information" do
    it "should not create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end

  describe "with valid information" do
    before do
      fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
      fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
      fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
      fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
    end

    it "should create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end

    describe "edit" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

      describe "page" do
        it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
        it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
      end

      describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Save changes" }

        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Indenting your code properly will make missing `end`s quite obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an end missing in your code, you should try to format your code correctly, it might help you get things right faster:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button "Create my account" }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "error messages" do
        before { click_button "Create my account" }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect do
          click_button "Create my account"
        end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button "Create my account" }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end
    end
  end
end

describe "signup page" do
  before { visit signup_path }

  it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

describe "signup" do

  before { visit signup_path }

  let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

  describe "with invalid information" do
    it "should not create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end

  describe "with valid information" do
    before do
      fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
      fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
      fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
      fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
    end

    it "should create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
    describe "edit" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

      describe "page" do
        it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
        it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
      end

      describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Save changes" }

        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? What didnt work? How it didn't work? My crystal ball isn't behaving today :) (RubyMine says this code is valid, btw) - see the code in a gist here - https://gist.github.com/1664206717def0774de2

Comment: Sorry Mauricio, the test didn't pass. Terminal returned this:

Comment: Check the gist up there again - https://gist.github.com/1664206717def0774de2 - the nesting is now corrected to make all tests happen inside the very first describe.

Comment: See at the bottom of the page for the Terminal return

Comment: This line 113 doesn't exist on my code - https://skitch.com/mauricio-linhares/89ttp/spec.rb-transitoweb-projects-ruby-transitoweb

Comment: sis-macbook-pro:sample_app Lagaspi$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "edit page"
/Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /Users/Lagaspi/rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

Comment: Now your users_controller.rb file has a syntax error. @SimonCliff you should try to use RubyMine to detect this stuff for you, you will not move forward having syntax issues on every single file you write.

Comment: OK, i'll look into that - thanks very much for your help. Ive only been at this for 2 weeks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an `end` at the end of your file. There is a mismatching do which has no `end`. try putting in (one or two) `end` at the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

Please check it

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
      before { visit signup_path }

      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

      before { visit signup_path }

      describe "with invalid information" do
        it "should not create a user" do
          expect { click_button "Create my account" }.not_to change(User, :count)
        end

        describe "error messages" do
          before { click_button "Create my account" }

          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
          it { should have_content('error') }
        end
      end

      describe "with valid information" do
        before do
          fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
          fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
          fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
          fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
        end

        it "should create a user" do
          expect do
            click_button "Create my account"
          end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

        describe "after saving the user" do
          before { click_button "Create my account" }
          let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

          it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
          it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
          it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        end
      end
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
      describe "edit" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { visit edit_user_path(user) }

      describe "page" do
        it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
        it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
      end

      describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Save changes" }

        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end
  end
end
end
```